# Typescript generics, constraints and literal types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following generic function:

```
type Identity = <T extends string | number>(arg: T) => T;
const identity: Identity = (x) => x;
```

If I attempt to use this function like so, I get errors that I cannot reassign.

```
let a = identity('a');
a = 'b'; // Error: Type '"b"' is not assignable to type '"a"'

let b = identity(1);
b = 2; // Error: Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'
```

I would expect the type returned from `identity` to be either a `string` or `number`, however it seems I am getting literal types back of `'a'` and `1`. Why is this the case? and is there a way to change my constraints so this is the behaviour?

I've have found a couple of workarounds. Firstly to assign the parameter to a variable first:

```
let a_param = 'a'
let a = identity(a_param);
a = 'b'; // Yay

let b_param = 1;
let b = identity(b_param);
b = 2; // Yay
```

And secondly to cast to a `string` or `number`:

```
let a = identity('a' as string);
a = 'b'; // Yay

let b = identity(1 as number);
b = 2; // Yay
```

Both of these feel wrong. I'm still learning TS so I think I've missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameter will normally be inferred as the most specific possible type consistent with the argument; in this case, the string literal type `'a'`. This is almost always the desired behaviour.

In your case, the inferred type is too strict because you are using it as the inferred type of a variable, not just the inferred type of an expression. So a natural solution is to specify a weaker type parameter, like so:

```
let a = identity<string>('a');
```

However, it would be more normal to simply specify the type of the variable:

```
let a: string = identity('a');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a generic but your requirements are antithetical to generics. This is because `identity('a')` actually means `identity<'a'>('a')` therefore the return type is `'a'` (not any string).

What works (for some reason) is:

```
type Identity = {
  (arg: number): number;
  (arg: string): string;
}

const identity: Identity = (x: any) => x;

let a = identity('a');
a = 'b'; // yes
a = 3; // no

let b = identity(1);
b = 'b'; // no
b = 3; // yes
```

I *think* how this works is it resolves which of the overloads best matches within the type `Identity` when you call the function which implements that type.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAdsAlqKBeKBvAUFKACgEMAnAcwC4pEBXAWwCMJSBKauplgbnyLKpQAzsFIpE5dsNHjyvAL65cAYwD2iEVBQJkaENXhJU6LIQAe1YohCtMAPihneuADYRgUYpi07jIQgDkxAGsvF5YAYwB3FC44VAAzM5uHoze2kZ6hACMobhpEVEx%20d5JuEA)